# Wrong rotation of object while rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, error

The viewport is completely fine, but while rendering, the rotation of the donut is different.
Here's a comparison.

[image: comparison]

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's a rotation problem, the distribution is different in the two images

Comment: Hello, maybe you have 2 particle systems? Please share your file

Comment: @Gorgious , I don't think its the distribution, I rotated it a lot of times, yet it stays the same.

Comment: There's a difference but I don't know the geonodes enough to answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Subdiv. modifier is set to level 1 in the viewport, and 2 in the render. It is above the GN that distributes the sprinkles.

The *Distribute Points on Faces* algorithm must be topology-based, so appears to consider the level 2 subdiv. to be completely different from the level 1 subdiv. :

[image]

If you set the viewport level the same as the render level, no difference... or, maybe, subdivide the icing inside the GN, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Without a .blend file it is hard to tell, but I think your Donut is animated and if you render the Scene the donut will follow that animation. Look in the Timeline if your Donut is animated and delete the keyframes :)

Comment: heres the link: https://www.mediafire.com/file/kt5ltbqt08pp7ou/donutlighting2.blend/file , by the way it isnt an animation.

Comment: @moonboots i downloaded it but it works fine, here's a new link: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/167QdeRMMQ1gInG2YeUWhg3LPNlx7zjfR/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Oh ok my bad you're using a geonode for the particles  ;)